# iText7 changes font of form fields

Tags: fonts, itext7

I am trying to fill an existing PDF using itext7. The template has already set fonts with all properties (size, colour, endoding etc). I fill the form using setValue method of the field:

`form.getField(name).setValue(myValue)`

result is much different from the template. I was trying to get information about font from the field and iText sets it to Helvetica with size set to 8.64 and no color.

I know I can set font manually but I would prefer to use the one that is already set i my template. Does anyone know how can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure Helvetica font contains the glyphs you need for setting the value? Can you attach your code and sample PDF to reproduce?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @cjimenecue I have created a new template and don't have this problem anymore. However, I'd like to know how to solve it in the future in case it appears again. Maybe it was just some issue in template's metadata.

Comment: *"I'd like to know how to solve it in the future in case it appears again. Maybe it was just some issue in template's metadata."* - In that case you should share the template with the issue; obviously there is something special about it causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please:

```
// Get your field and save it in a variable
var field = form.getField(name);

// Get field's font and size
PdfFont font = field.GetFont();
float fontSize = field.GetFontSize();

// Apply style to your field
field.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);

// Set a value to your field
field.setValue(myValue);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried this and it was returning Helvetica instead of Arial (original font in my template).